# IE7 and the statusbar

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, popup, statusbar

Is there a way to spawn a new window via javascript in IE7 that hides the statusbar?

I've added the intranet app as a trusted site. Not sure what else I can use to try. This is my JS

```
window.open("http:/localhost/start.html", "MyApp", "left=0, top=0, width=" + screen.width + "," +
                              "height=" + screen.height + ", scrollbars=yes, " + 
                              "resizable=yes, location=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, " + "toolbar=no, status=no");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**  Microsoft decided that **"in the name of security"** ([IE Blog Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/08/25/719355.aspx)) they would force the status bar to show on popup windows in IE7. (they also force a new minimum width of ~250px instead of the 100px it used to be - this is so they can show the url in the readonly dropdown location bar thing)

Sorry.

Comment: IMO this would be a great answer if you provided a link to the Microsoft document where you got the quotation.

Comment: It was on the IE Blog, I'll see if I can dig up the reference.

Comment: Found it: http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/08/25/719355.aspx
quote: "In Windows XP Service Pack 2, IE’s security improvements added window restrictions that forced the status bar onto windows and dialogs (in certain security zones); "

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me, [and here's a screenshot.](http://img511.imageshack.us/my.php?image=workshq7.png)

Example of how IE7 renders popup without status bar. http://img511.imageshack.us/img511/7757/workshq7.th.png

Note that experment was done on local filesystem, with "Protected Mode" completly turned off. If it didn't work for you, my guess is that your security settings is somehow still to high. Tinkering with the browser UI trough JavaScript is usually blocked for security reasons and should not be relied on.

Comment: this works on the local machine only. If on the public Internet, it will not work.